# Forward all requests to subdirectory in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I realize this question has been asked many times but I have been trying for a while now and cannot get any of the previously posted solutions to work for me.

I have a webapp app hosted on my site at: www.example.com/app/

At the heart of the app is an index.php file that resides in www.example.com/app/www/

What I need is for all requests on the site to be forwarded to this /www/ subdirectory.

For example, www.example.com/app/ will forward to www.example.com/app/www/

and www.example.com/app/view/ will forward to www.example.com/app/www/view/

Thank you for any help that anyone can offer on this matter. It's been driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your htaccess file in your document root (the directory that "app" is in) doesn't work?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/www/
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ /app/www/$1 [L]
```

Comment: That does not work for me. When I go to what is supposed to be the root of the site (www.example.com/app/) I get a directory listing page when I should be getting the contents of (www.example.com/app/www/).